# Trying to find a certain function over a DAG's vertices

Tags: sequences-and-series, graph-theory

Given a rooted, transitively reduced DAG, I'm trying to find a (addendum: non-constant) function that assigns a [fixed-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) (whether the unit is some fixed rational or $1$ doesn't especially matter) to every vertex in the graph which has the following properties:

1. The value assigned to a given vertex can only depend on its ancestors, not on any siblings or children that it may have. This is because the graph will be "built" a single vertex at a time (always being a transitive reduction) and I want to be able to compute a vertex's value as soon as it is added to the graph, without that value changing as a result of new nodes coming in, regardless of their relation to existing nodes.
2. In the limit of an arbitarily deep graph, the combined sum of nodes in *all* paths back up to the root, counting each node only once, is not only finite but bounded from above by a value that can be known ahead of time, i.e. isn't dependent on the specific graph layout. Put another way, a new vertex that has multiple parents should neither make any of those parents "disappear", nor "double-count" the value of parents' common ancestry in terms of the sum back to the root. As an example, borrowing this graph from Wikipedia:

[image]

If we assign all of the nodes a value of $1$, then the value of the path from $e$ to $a$ is 5, *not*
6 as it would be if the value of $a$ were counted twice from the path through $b$ and the path through $c$. That said, $f(V)=1$ is not an assignment that meets these criteria because it is not bounded as the graph gets deeper.

The function is allowed to start positive and then become zero after some depth, (which I think is required) so I'd also appreciate if anything can be said about how this depth might be determined.

Also, I don't know for sure that such a function exists at all, so I'd appreciate if anyone could point out any extra assumptions needed to make this solveable

Comment: Is the function allowed to equal $0$? If yes, then assigning $0$ to every vertex works. If not (and if every value must be a multiple of some fixed unit) then the sum can be arbitrarily large, because there might be arbitrarily long paths.

Comment: It should not be 0 everywhere, but it is allowed to become zero after some finite/fixed depth, so I don't see how the arbitrarily long paths are necessarily an obstacle

Comment: If it is not $0$ everywhere, then what's the exact restriction? Can I just assign $1$ to the root and $0$ to all other vertices? (And are you assuming that there's a root with a path to every other vertex?)

Comment: Sorry, yeah, I am assuming there's a single root, added that to the question. As for the restriction, uh... I need to think about that more carefully, but my intuition was that the function was "count down" and have a non-zero value for a meaningful depth, so say, it should assign a non-zero value to nodes at depth 5. 
(Rewrote this comment to define intuition better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the restrictions on $f$ that:

1. For every node $v$, $f(v)$ is a nonnegative integer.
2. There is a unique root $r$ of indegree $0$ (so that the third restriction makes sense).
3. There is some universal constant $C$ such that in any such graph, for every $v$, the sum of values $f(u)$ of the nodes $u$ that lie on some path from $r$ to $v$ is at most $C$.
4. For every node $v$, $f(v)$ is determined only by its ancestors: say, by the subgraph induced by all nodes that lie on some path from $r$ to $v$.

Then either $f \equiv 0$ for all nodes, or only $f(r) \ne 0$.

To see this, suppose there is any graph $G$ in which $f(v) \ne 0$ for some $v \ne r$. We build $C+1$ copies of $G$, all sharing the root $r$, each with their own copy of $v$: call those copies $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{C+1}$. By the 4th condition, $f(v_1), f(v_2), \dots, f(v_{C+1})$ must all be nonzero, and therefore at least $1$.

Now add a final node $w$ with arcs from each of $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{C+1}$ to $w$. This node $w$ violates the 3rd condition: the sum of $f$-values of nodes that lie on paths from $r$ to $w$ is at least $C+1$.

For example, if you're willing to assign a nonzero value to a node whose only ancestor is $r$, then this counterexample just has vertices $r, v_1, \dots, v_{C+1}, w$ with arcs $(r, v_i)$ and $(v_i, w)$ for $1 \le i \le C+1$.)

Comment: This is a good proof, which means I need to back to the drawing board. Just to check an obvious-seeming patch, does your argument still go through if there is a maximum depth allowed between a node with multiple parents and those parents' MRCA? (So we can't have arbitarily long independent branches)

Comment: Not immediately, but there's a modification we can do that might actually make my construction simpler. Instead of building separate copies of $G$, just take a single copy of $G$ and create more copies of $v$: more nodes that have the same set of parents as $v$ does. If those are $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_{C+1}$, then the same argument as before continues to hold, and this doesn't require long independent branches.